# Bootstrap Navbar custom design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I am having some problems with the bootstrap system. I have used it for a while, but it always seems a bit PLAIN. The navbar is just plain one color, or even a bit of gradient. But I wanted to know if I could make my navbar something like this: [CoinURL - Bitcoins](http://coinurl.com) I can't seem to find any thing on the internet explaining how to make it look like there navbar. I just need to have that extra line that it has on top fro the active link.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Fixed, this was fixed with the help of: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529485/nix
The solution was simple, add this to your CSS Custom design file:

```
.navbar-fixed-top { border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(11, 166, 240); } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a { border-top: 3px solid white; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > li { background: #fff; }
```

Comment: Add border-bottom to the navigation UL and border-top to list items. GIYF.

Comment: Sorry, could you please give me some code maybe? I cannot seem to get this. I find CSS a bit confusing, while I think design is probably not my friend :(

Comment: Erm sure. Other's solution didn't seem to work for you, did you change structure of navigation structure?

Comment: Actually, its more of a gpEasy CMS, so editing it is a *BIT* harder. As you can take a look at it: http://jetlink.bd.to/d/9d72fb4f23 This is my test site, so as of yet, it is not complete and not in production mode. Thanks.

Comment: All right. Try this: .navbar-fixed-top { border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(11, 166, 240); } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a { border-top: 3px solid white; } .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > li { background: #fff; }

Comment: PS: your website's CSS is being served through cache. Try clearing that once if the CSS I provided doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! It worked! Your ID is going up on my hall of thanks when it is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude just add a border-top: 3px solid #000; to your links?

Like in Bootstrap i think it would be like

.navbar-nav li:active{

border-top: 3px solid #000;
}

(Use !important after your color if it doesn't work)

Have a nice day!

Comment: This is somewhat the answer. But not exactly, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. See the 7 examples of customized navbar on [Bootsnipp here](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/navbar).

Click on the corresponding **View** button to see the demo as well as the source code of each navbar customization.

As for the colors for the navbar, check out  [TWBSColor](http://smarchal.com/twbscolor/) : It lets you create a customized color navbar for bootstrap very quickly and easily online.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I cannot seem to find any one with the extra line on top like the Coin URL site. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. The Examples will be of great use and so will the tool. Thank you! :)